# Can I cover a scaffolding block in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to find a way to **cover a scaffolding block in Minecraft, but still be able to walk through it**. I've tried paintings, item frames, and signs, but none of them worked.

Does anyone know a way to do it? I know this sounds like a really nooby question, but I've been playing this game almost since it came out (I remember the simplicity of 1.12.2, before Microsoft bought Mojang) and I genuinely can't figure out how to do this. Also, keep in mind, I'm not on Java edition, I'm on Nintendo Switch (Bedrock Edition).

Comment: do you mean vertically or horizontally

Comment: On Java Edition, single snow layer is intangible and can be placed on top of a scaffolding.

Answer (score 2):

[According to this video and Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/9v13xf/you_can_create_simple_hidden_areas_using/), you can **cover scaffolding with snow** and still be able to go down it, walk through it, etc.

This works because Minecraft considers snow to be intangible - that is, it has no inherent collision or physics logic - and therefore the player can just pass right through it.